# Is there a way to guarantee the running of some code whenever an iOS app closes?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried putting my code in the `applicationWillTerminate` function of the app delegate but noticed it wasn't being called when I closed the app and then read up and found out `applicationWillTerminate` is not called consistently on app close. What the heck?

Is there any way to consistently execute code on app close? It seems like a simple requirement and it is important for my project so I hope this is possible.

Comment: Use `silent push notifications` if you want to perform some background task when app is not running.

Comment: Run your code when your app enters the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applicationWillTerminate` is not normally called. You get a message when your app is about to be suspended, and once that happens you can be terminated without further warning. you should treat a suspend event as a possible termination and save everything you need to save.

As I recall it is possible to get notified about UNIX SIGTERM messages, but I'm not positive.

Comment: thanks! how do i tap into/act on this message that is sent when the app is about to be suspended?

Comment: It looks like I remembered wrong and the message that will be sent to your app delegate is `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)`.  If you want to respond to the background notification somewhere else than your app delegate you can also register for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` notification.